# Access to Google API without using a json file

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

Is there a way to avoid using the **client_secret.json** file and use variables from it by declaring them programmatically in the project setup files?
I mean instead of using

```
  KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '/home/user/ga/client_secrets.json'
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
```

smth like this
**settings.py**

```
CLIENT_CONFIG = {
    ....
    'client_id': settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    'project_id': settings.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    'private_key': settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    .....

    }
```

**main.py**

```
  from settings import CLIENT_CONFIG
    
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.SOME_FUNCTION(
      CLIENT_CONFIG, SCOPES)
```

Comment: You should be able to.  its just loading it into an object but im not a python dev but check the source for the library might help https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/blob/50d20532a748f18e53f7d24ccbe6647132c979a9/scripts/run_system_tests.py#L84

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can be done by using the function **from_json_keyfile_dict**
https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/blob/50d20532a748f18e53f7d24ccbe6647132c979a9/oauth2client/service_account.py#L226
passing in the contents of the json file as a variable

```
data = {
...
json file content
....
}
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
      data, SCOPES)
```

Answer (score 0):

file *config.cfg*

```
[creds]
client_id = GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
project_id = GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID
```

*main.py*

```py
import configparser as cfg

parser = cfg.ConfigParser()
parser.read('path of config.cfg file')
client_id = parser.get('creds','client_id ')
project_id = parser.get('creds','project_id ')
```